# Creating Divs on same line please

Tags: html

Having a hard time creating this icon page. Basically, I want the icons to line up near each other so it is basically something like this ...

Custom Icon- Pencil      Custom Icon - clock
The Icon of the pencil   The Icon of the clock

```
<div>
    <!-- Icon Button - pencil -->
    Custom Icon - pencil <br />
    <div id="pencil">pencil</div>
</div>

<div>
    <!-- Icon Button - clock -->
    Custom Icon - clock <br />
    <div id="clock">clock</div>
</div>

<div>
    <!-- Icon Button - disk -->
    Custom Icon - disk <br />
    <div id="disk">disk</div>
</div>

<div>
    <!-- Icon Button - calendar -->
    Custom Icon - calendar <br />
    <div id="calendar">calendar</div>
</div>

<div>
    <!-- Icon Button - zoomin -->
    Custom Icon - zoomin <br />
    <div id="zoomin">zoomin</div>
</div>

<div>
    <!-- Icon Button - zoomout -->
    Custom Icon - zoomout <br />
    <div id="zoomout">zoomout</div>
</div>
```

I have a gazillion pre-made buttons I would like to show on a page for the staff :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm having a hard time understanding exactly what you're looking for but I can give some general pointers.  If you have divs and you want to line them up horizontally, the most common way to achieve that is with `float` in CSS.

[Here's a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4SBS9/).

What's happening here?  I made 3 divs and they're lined up next to each other.  I gave each of them two classes.  They all have class `icon`, which controls the behavior of all three.  Then each one has a second class to define their individual behavior.  There's also text inside them to demonstrate how you can fill those divs with other content.

The important point for lining them up is that they're all `float: left` and they all have a set `width`.  Setting the width will probably be important for your layout, unless the content all has a specific width - in which case you'd probably be happy just using `padding`.

If I'm completely missing your point, try to clarify and I'll give it another go.